# %APPDATA% "half" broken after linking Microsoft Account

Tags: windows-10, environment-variables

A couple of days ago I reinstalled the OS of my laptop. At first I created a local account since I don't have memorized the password of the Microsoft account (I use KeePass for that) and later I linked my Microsoft Account to this new installation, but since then I've been unable to access to AppData folder from "Run" window using the environment variable `%APPDATA%`, but, If I use that variable on an Explorer window (on the address bar) it works fine. When I try to open the folder the "Run" window the system ask me "How do you want to open this file" as its shown here:

[image: How do you want to open this file?]

The first time that it happened to me was when I started to receive the Insider updates on another laptop (after I made a fresh install), and I blamed such updates. But in this one I'm using a "normal" version of Windows.

At first I asked on the [Insider Forums](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_files/cant-access-to-appdata-folder-from-run-windows-r/e02c9c59-a206-478c-ada1-3232a9c3b973) but it was until this month that someone gave a clue about which can be the problem (or I figured out that I was having the same issue as that person).

As a side note, I must note that my username isn't just one word, but two (my first and last name) but with a space between: `C:\Users\Antonio Gil\`. I note this because the user who posted earlier this month, mentioned that he "opened" the `%APPDATA%` with Wordpad, it shows his security identifier (SID). In my case, it doesn't show that, it shows this:

[image: Wordpad]

As you can see, on the Title Bar is just the first part of my name (Antonio) and the rest is missing. The person who made the comment notices that his username (one word) is on the Title Bar so I'm guessing that in my case, being my username two separated words, there is some kind of trouble.

And now I'm more lost than before because I don't know what are the OS is trying to do.

On another side note, other variables as `%USREPROFILE%`, and `%LOCALAPPDATA%` are in the same situation.

So, any idea on how "fix" the value of `%APPDATA%` to be able to open that folder from the "Run" window again?

Thanks in advance.

Regards!

Comment: I suspect that your two-word user name is the major contributing factor. I always configure my entire family to start off with a one-word local account user name on our Windows 10 machines, and then convert them to our Microsoft accounts. After that, our display name will *then* appear as our full name while the profile in our C:\Users\ folder remains as the original one-word login (our first names), and everything works perfectly. I would backup my pertinent user files to either a USB drive or the Public folders, delete the problematic profile, and create a new one as I described above.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the response.

I guess that you're right, and I need to create another account using the procedure that you had described. I was hoping that it could be fixed without creating another account, but well, I guess it's the best option.

Regards!

(P.S. Thank you for the edits)

Comment: Not at all... we are always glad to help!

Comment: The problem is indeed your username.  The way you solve this is to disconnect your Microsoft Account from your account, when you do this you are given a chance to create a new profile, create this new profile using one word (no spaces) no special characters.  Once the new local profile is created you can connect that account to your MS account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that your two-word user name is the major contributing factor.

Personally, I always initially configure my entire family to start off with a one-word local account user name on our Windows 10 machines, and then convert them to our Microsoft accounts. After that, our display name will then appear as our full name while our profile folder in `C:\Users\` retains the original one-word nomenclature (our first names), and everything works perfectly.

Faced with the same scenario, I would backup my pertinent user files to either a USB drive or the `Public` folders, delete the problematic profile, and create a new one as I described above.

Comment: Easier solution.  Disconnect the MS account which prompts for the creation of a new local user account.  Windows will handle the profile migration.  Once that happens the author can simply link the new local profile to the MS account and the problem will be fixed.

Comment: @Ramhound, an excellent suggestion, good sir!  I have never converted in the *other* direction, so I didn't know that you get prompted for the creation of a **new** local user account.  Good to know.

Comment: typically if you create an account and indicate you want your account linked to a MS account, the profile created, contain the MS username.  However, if you link an existing local account to a MS account, the same profile directory will be used (for the new account that is created).  You can use this to your advantage, because while the same profile directory is used, a new account actually was created.  So the reverse is true, when you unlink a MS account, you are prompted for what account you want to be created, and by default the original profile will be used (unless you change it)

Comment: Windows handles ownership changes silently which is the reason you are required to log out of the profile to connect/disconnect a MS account from a local user account profile.

Comment: @Ramhound, I certainly appreciate the enlightenment.  I had a good understanding of the local-to-Microsoft account conversion, but didn't know the repercussions of the Microsoft-to-local transition.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: I only know this because I reinstalled my OS 9 months ago, mistakenly created a local account with a different name, then linked the created account to my MS account.  I then realized the profile directory I wanted to use, didn't even exist, so I unlinked it and created a new local account to achieve that,

Comment: @Ramhound thanks for the suggestion! I'll try it late, when I go back home. But, what about all the user configuration/settings that exists already? Do you know, or have noticed if they will be affected for such action? (I know that it's better to make a backup before trying anything, but I wonder which is the effect on such files).

Thank you both for the support!